# How to stop Youtube video from overlapping thickbox frame?

Tags: html, css, youtube, thickbox

I'm using Thickbox to display videos on a website and the youtube video seems to be too large for the thickbox frame. I've tried decreasing the youtube video size but the thick box seems to follow the size of the video because no matter what I adjust the size to I always have this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl4PV.jpg

Notice in the bottom right corner, the video goes outside the frame. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is the html code for the video. Personal info has been removed (site name, youtube embed, etc.):

```
<a class="thickbox" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXX?rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600" title="XXXXXXXXX"><img src="http://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.org/campaign/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2013/11/XXXXXXXXXX.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need the full code to give a complete answer, but based on my experience with other plugins:

Most plugins have very specific styles that are sometimes difficult to override. Give the video a "class" and set the width to `width: 100% !important;` (or whatever). This should override the defaults set in place by the plugin.